# opening internet explorer with specific size and position on screen

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I want to open Internet Explorer with an especific size and in a specific position on screen.

I have found two ways of doing this:

The problem I have with the first is that, it does everything okay but it start to lag, making it impossible to use and I have to kill the program. I don't know why, because I use the same code to open Firefox and it works fine:

```
. C:\Users\user\git\testPowerShell/Set-Window.ps1
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:/Program Files/internet explorer/iexplore.exe' -ArgumentList https://www.facebook.com/
Start-Sleep -Seconds 0
Set-Window -ProcessName iexplore -x 100 -y 5 -Width 1176 -Height 715 -Passthru
```

The problem with second is that the windows that opens doesn't have focus, I really need that Internet Explorer opens on top of everything:

```
$ie = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application;
$ie.visible = $true;
#$ie2 = $ie.Width = 200;
$ie.top = 15; $ie.width = 1180; $ie.height = 710; $ie.Left = 192;
$ie.navigate('https://www.facebook.com/');
```

Any solution to either approach?

---

Also, Set-Windows.ps1 is like this

```
Function Set-Window {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Sets the window size (height,width) and coordinates (x,y) of
            a process window.

        .DESCRIPTION
            Sets the window size (height,width) and coordinates (x,y) of
            a process window.

        .PARAMETER ProcessName
            Name of the process to determine the window characteristics

        .PARAMETER X
            Set the position of the window in pixels from the top.

        .PARAMETER Y
            Set the position of the window in pixels from the left.

        .PARAMETER Width
            Set the width of the window.

        .PARAMETER Height
            Set the height of the window.

        .PARAMETER Passthru
            Display the output object of the window.

        .NOTES
            Name: Set-Window
            Author: Boe Prox
            Version History
                1.0//Boe Prox - 11/24/2015
                    - Initial build
                1.1//JosefZ (https://superuser.com/users/376602/josefz) - 19.05.2018
                    - treats more process instances of supplied process name properly

        .OUTPUT
            System.Automation.WindowInfo

        .EXAMPLE
            Get-Process powershell | Set-Window -X 2040 -Y 142 -Passthru

            ProcessName Size     TopLeft  BottomRight
            ----------- ----     -------  -----------
            powershell  1262,642 2040,142 3302,784   

            Description
            -----------
            Set the coordinates on the window for the process PowerShell.exe

    #>
    [OutputType('System.Automation.WindowInfo')]
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        $ProcessName,
        [int]$X,
        [int]$Y,
        [int]$Width,
        [int]$Height,
        [switch]$Passthru
    )
    Begin {
        Try{
            [void][Window]
        } Catch {
        Add-Type @"
              using System;
              using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
              public class Window {
                [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
                public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

                [DllImport("User32.dll")]
                public extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);
              }
              public struct RECT
              {
                public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
                public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
                public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
                public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
              }
"@
        }
    }
    Process {
        $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
        $Handles = (Get-Process -Name $ProcessName).MainWindowHandle   ### 1.1//JosefZ
        foreach ( $Handle in $Handles ) {                              ### 1.1//JosefZ
            if ( $Handle -eq [System.IntPtr]::Zero ) { Continue }      ### 1.1//JosefZ
            $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
            If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Width')) {            
                $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left            
            }
            If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Height')) {
                $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
            }
            If ($Return) {
                $Return = [Window]::MoveWindow($Handle, $x, $y, $Width, $Height,$True)
            }
            If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Passthru')) {
                $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
                $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
                If ($Return) {
                    $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
                    $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left
                    $Size = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size -ArgumentList $Width, $Height
                    $TopLeft = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Left, $Rectangle.Top
                    $BottomRight = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Right, $Rectangle.Bottom
                    If ($Rectangle.Top -lt 0 -AND $Rectangle.LEft -lt 0) {
                        Write-Warning "Window is minimized! Coordinates will not be accurate."
                    }
                    $Object = [pscustomobject]@{
                        ProcessName = $ProcessName
                        Size = $Size
                        TopLeft = $TopLeft
                        BottomRight = $BottomRight
                    }
                    $Object.PSTypeNames.insert(0,'System.Automation.WindowInfo')
                    $Object            
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it starts to lag?

Comment: the mouse cursor keeps "thinking" and I can´t scroll or anything

Comment: You should see why your IE is doing that. Thats not normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second method, you could use:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class Win32SetWindow {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    }
"@

$ie = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application;
$ie.visible = $true;
#$ie2 = $ie.Width = 200;
$ie.top = 15; $ie.width = 1180; $ie.height = 710; $ie.Left = 192;

     [Win32SetWindow]::SetForegroundWindow($ie.HWND) # <--

$ie.navigate('https://www.facebook.com/');
```

Comment: I tried this but it dos not work. I get InvalidOperation error with "width", "height", "left". And also null values while trying to execute [Win32SetWindow]::SetForegroundWindow($ie.HWND)
$ie.navigate('https://www.facebook.com/');

Comment: This was only an extraction of what the code should look like. I edited my post and pasted the full code.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use script below.

```html
$ie = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application

$ie.visible = $true

#$ie2 = $ie.Width = 200 

$ie.top = 100; $ie.width = 500; $ie.height = 500 ; $ie.Left = 100

$ie.navigate("http://google.com")
```

Reference:

[Open Internet Explorer in Specific Height and Width](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Open-Internet-Explorer-in-d91674ca)

Comment: Whats the difference with mine?