# open different internet explorer window

Tags: c, internet-explorer-11

I need to open automatically when the computer starts 3 different pages of internet explorer 11 with size fixed. So I don't need every reboot to resize manually

Is there a way ?? (with a c program or anything else?)

something like a setsize and set position for specific internet explorer page

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to find out about the command line usage of internet explorer with all available arguments. Then write a quick batch script and add it to your autostart. No need to write a c programm.

Comment: you are right thanks! I was able to do it using Powershell I use these settings :$IE.Left = 0
$IE.Width = 1350
$IE.Top = 0
$IE.Height = 1040 and it's working. The main problem is now that the "value" are fixed so if I change resolution or monitor I've to rewrite it

Comment: If you want to start IE in fullscrren mode try using "-k" option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't aware of any group policy setting that can limit the number of opened tabs in IE. Seems there is no limitation by the number of tabs. You can check [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-number-of-tabs-which/f0a70b3e-043a-483f-b16a-f94ae09f0574).

Besides, if you want to open internet explorer with specific size and position on screen, you could refer to this powershell script (code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52723823/opening-internet-explorer-with-specific-size-and-position-on-screen)):

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class Win32SetWindow {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    }
"@

$ie = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application;
$ie.visible = $true;
#$ie2 = $ie.Width = 200;
$ie.top = 15; $ie.width = 1180; $ie.height = 710; $ie.Left = 192;

     [Win32SetWindow]::SetForegroundWindow($ie.HWND) # <--

$ie.navigate('https://www.facebook.com/');
```